# Autohide launcher does not work ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher

Altough I've setted to autohide sometimes this feature does not work.

After restarting it works but after a short period of time again stops autohiding.

Any shortcut to hide launcher? Or how to solve problem?

Comment: I'm sorry my friend but it just enables or disables setting for hiding launcher. But not actually works. When i re-enable again it does not hides.

Answer (score 1):

Identifying the root cause of the problem would require to know which kind of installed packages/applications/service may overwrite this setting.

You can of course create a keyboard shortcut to quickly re-enable Autohide with the following command:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode 1
```

In order to identify the guilty application, you could use the following command in a terminal:

```
dconf watch /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode
```

and use System Monitor to list the running applications/services.